# How do I make a dynamic number of divs occupy all of the space in their container equally?

Tags: css, css-float

I have a container in which there is a dynamic number of divs. I want all of the divs to fit on one line without wrapping such that each div has the same width. Both the number of divs and the size of the screen can change. I'm hoping for a css solution.

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XnC6k/) the grey box should be filled with three equally-sized red, green, and blue rectangles.

I've tried this to no avail.

```
#container {
    width: 400px;
    border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
}

#container div {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: i think this will not work without js

Comment: Put them in a <table><tr><td> ... <td> will always spread equally ..

Comment: @chris .. i can do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make your html dividers behave like a table set. Table-dividers (`<td>`) are meant to spread evenly by default.

HTML

```
<div class="table-div" style="width:100%">
    <div class="tr-div">
        <div class="td-div">td-div 1a</div>
        <div class="td-div">td-div 2a</div>
        <div class="td-div">td-div 3a</div>
        <div class="td-div">td-div 3b</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr-div">
        <div class="td-div">td-div 1b</div>
        <div class="td-div">td-div 2b</div>
        <div class="td-div">td-div 3b</div>
        <div class="td-div">td-div 3b</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table-div{display:table} /* you can add table-layout:fixed; to suit your needs ([Yoshi][1])*/
.tr-div{display:table-row}
.td-div{display:table-cell;border:1px solid silver}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sPm9M/

Comment: This is the best solution. Just a single row is required for the answer.

Comment: I think you'll also need `table-layout: fixed;` on the `.tabel-div`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, no matter the size of the container, you would like the div to have all the same width and they fulfill all the container?

If this is the case, it's simple, you divide 100 by the number of div to include in the container to get the right percentage width of each div.

Here : http://jsfiddle.net/XnC6k/3/

Comment: I understand that, but since the number of div's changes, I would have to recalculate that value with JavaScript every time. I was hoping for a purely CSS solution.

Comment: +1 Indeed the solution Milche Patern is correct, I tried to use the counters css "counter-increment" but impossible to initialize a total counter for dividing the width by the number of div. http://jsfiddle.net/XnC6k/10/