# How can I make sure that a div tag gets auto height of the container height?

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a div container that changes size depending on a child div content inside like if its 3 lines of texts the container ofcourse get higher height automaticly.

I have a child div next to the child div tag that has the content. I would like to make sure that it changes height just like the div with the content.

Here is an example

[image]

Any kind of help is appreciated

Here is the markup and css:

```
<div class="announcement>
  <div class="color-blind-warning"><img src="icon-alert.png"/></div>
  <div class="content">
            <div class="titleText">Testing testing testing</div>
            <div class="expand"></div>          
            <div class="ms-clear" style="margin-bottom: 3px;"></div>
                <div class="calendar-image">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="title-date">25 dec, kl: 05:30</div>
            <div class="ms-clear"></div>
  </div>


</div>
```

CSS:

```
.color-blind-warning{
float: left;
width: 42px;
background-color: #e6433e;
height: auto;
}

.title {  
            background-position: 7px 7px;
            padding: 5px 15px 5px 10px;
            .expand {
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: middle;
                background-image: url('ner.png');
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                margin-top:5px;
                margin-right: -6px;
                width: 16px;
                height: 16px;               
                padding:0;
                float:right;
            }
            .titleText {
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: middle;
                width: 220px;
                font-size: 12px !important;
                margin-bottom: -7px;

            }   
            .title-date {
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: middle;
                font-size: 11px !important;
                margin-left: 5px;
                float:left;
                margin-bottom:5px;
            }   
            .calendar-image
            {
                height:14px;
                width:14px;
                background-image: url('icon-importantmessages.png') !important;
                float:left;
            }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496788/how-do-i-make-a-dynamic-number-of-divs-occupy-all-of-the-space-in-their-containe/18497140#18497140

Comment: I am not using a Table structure with div tags

Comment: Which div is getting larger and which do you want to resize?

Comment: @Zeaklous I want to resize the color-blind warning div to the containers height size when it gets content. the container div tag is  announcement

Comment: Have you tried giving `.color-blind-warning` `height:100%`?

Comment: yes, but it wont resize to the containers height beacuse the .color-blind-warning have a image in there that have height of 60px

Answer (score 0):

Hi you Can work with the `display` property instead of `float`  -->

```
.announcement {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
.color-blind-warning {
  display:table-cell;
  height:100%;
  width:30%;
}
.content {
  display:table-cell;
  width:70%;
}
```

Review this demo **http://jsfiddle.net/93uUg/16/**